# Laravel add method to a vendor class

Tags: laravel

In laravel we can use `with()` along with `redirect()`, like

```
return redirect('home')->with(['message' => 'Some message');
```

I want to create some other functions like `withError()`, `withSuccess()`.

How and where to create this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Laravel [RedirectResponse class](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html) uses the [Macroable trait](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html), you can register [response macros](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#response-macros) to do this.

Just create a new service provider say `ResponseMacroServiceProvider`. Register it in your `app.php` and register a macro in the boot method like so:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application's response macros.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        RedirectResponse::macro('withError', function ($value) {
            return; // add logic here
        });

        RedirectResponse::macro('withSuccess', function ($value) {
            return; // add logic here
        });
    }
}
```